# Parsing consecutive non-terminals

Tags: context-free-grammar

I know I am supposed to have `T-> UU`, and have the first `parse_U` only parse "`aabb`", and the second `parse_U` would only parse the last "`ab`", but I cannot figure out how to do this with append. I can only retrieve a sub-list that starts with `a` and ends with `b`, but that is not the result I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you have problem with your code, you should show it to us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parsing in Prolog, I suggest the use of DCG (Definite Clause Grammar), when available.

If I'm not wrong, your grammar could simply become

```
isS --> isT.
isS --> isV.

isT --> isU, isU.

isU --> [a], isU, [b].
isU --> [a, b].

isV --> [a], isV, [b].
isV --> [a], isW, [b].

isW --> [b], isW, [a].
isW --> [b, a].
```

and can be used calling `isS(L, [])`, where L is a list with the sequence to parse.

Calling

```
isS([a,a,b,b,a,b], [])
```

you should obtain true.

**--- EDIT ---**

> this is homework and we are not allowed to use "-->"

There is nothing special in DGC (use of `-->`) syntax; it's only a semplification of the usual syntax.

If I'm not wrong, you can write the DCS syntax above as (caution: undescores added in rules names)

```
is_S(Lin, Lout) :- is_T(Lin, Lout).
is_S(Lin, Lout) :- is_V(Lin, Lout).

is_T(Lin, Lout) :- is_U(Lin, Lmid), is_U(Lmid, Lout).

is_U([a | Tin], Lout)      :- is_U(Tin, [b | Lout]).
is_U([a, b | Lout], Lout).

is_V([a | Tin], Lout)      :- is_V(Tin, [b | Lout]).
is_V([a | Tin], Lout)      :- is_W(Tin, [b | Lout]).

is_W([b | Tin], Lout)      :- is_W(Tin, [a | Lout]).
is_W([b, a | Lout], Lout).
```

Calling

```
is_S([a,a,b,b,a,b], [])
```

you should obtain true.

Comment: @Solace - you're wellcome; improved my answer to propose a traditional (no `-->` syntax) version of my solution.